# Core Data Sorting Error

Tags: sorting, core-data

I am attempting to sort a core data array by an entity called company. However, my app currently doesn't sort the data with the code I'm using. What's up?

Here is the error:

```
2013-11-15 17:07:59.615 Minutes[70925:a0b] (
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x89d4d40> (entity: Device; id: 0x89bdff0 <x-coredata://29EA13EB-909E-46E8-B8FD-C71A9B6436CE/Device/p2> ; data: {\n    company = Reading;\n    name = 1;\n    version = \"Minutes of Harry Potter\";\n})",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x89d4ad0> (entity: Device; id: 0x8986ff0 <x-coredata://29EA13EB-909E-46E8-B8FD-C71A9B6436CE/Device/p1> ; data: {\n    company = Service;\n    name = 2;\n    version = \"Minutes of Community\";\n})",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x89d4db0> (entity: Device; id: 0x8997950 <x-coredata://29EA13EB-909E-46E8-B8FD-C71A9B6436CE/Device/p3> ; data: {\n    company = Service;\n    name = 0;\n    version = \"Minutes of Blank\";\n})"
)
```

Here is the code used to sort the array:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:
                                      @"company" ascending:YES]];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT: Here is some code showing how I display the data:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.devices.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [device valueForKey:@"name"], [device valueForKey:@"version"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"company"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your array seems to be sorted correctly with respect to the "company" attribute.

Comment: worthy to note that you can set the sort descriptors directly on the fetch request instead of sorting it afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as expected. "Reading" <= "Service" <= "Service".

You sort `self.devices` into `sortedPeople`, but in your table view's datasource you are displaying `self.devices` which is unsorted.

Attach the sort descriptor to the fetch request and dispense with the `sortedPeople` array, and you your code should work as expected again.

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:
      @"company" ascending:YES]];
```

Also, not that you probably have a type in your cell method: it should be NSManagedObject, not NSManagedObjectModel. I recommend to use a subclass named `Device` (Xcode can auto generate that for you) and use its properties rather than Key-Value-Coding.

Edit:

BTW. If you change something *after* you use it, then whatever you used it for will not include that change. For example:

```
x = 1;
y = x + 1;  // y == 2
x = 3;      // y == 2 (nothing changed for y)
y = x + 1;  // y == 4 (y was used after the change)
```

The same applies to fetch results generated by executing fetches (y) and the corresponding fetch request (x).

Comment: Yes. It would seem that way. However, when I run the application, it doesn't display that way. It shows most recent on bottom. Thoughts?

Comment: Show how you display them.

Comment: Please see my amended answer.

Comment: Check your attribute names both in the model and in your managed object subclasses. The error you quote seems to indicate that you forgot to link the text field in storyboard. Make sure you have a `IBOutlet` property for it and that the name is correct. -- This has nothing to do with the problem - you should accept the answer.

Comment: I have made some changes to my code and have updated my question. My data still doesn't sort. Is there something that I didn't do right?

Comment: You add the sort descriptor **after** you execute the fetch request (facepalm).

Comment: Tried this. Still sorts my data most recent at the bottom.

Comment: You have to give sufficient information to answer your questions. Do some thinking. Is the `ascending` argument correct? Is the most recent at bottom because this corresponds to the company sorting? Compare the data in your database with your expected results. Make more comprehensive and systematic attempts and tell us rather than just "it does not work." Post your managed object model and the relevant parts of your device class.

Comment: Sorry for my vague details. The current doesn't correspond to the company sorting. Would a void like this: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
    help fix the problem?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my comment above. Of course you have to add the sort descriptor **before** executing the fetch request - you did that, right?

Comment: Could you please update your answer to show where I should insert the sort descriptor?